# Why Django logging skips log entries?

Tags: python, django, django-logging

This is my settings module:

```
LOGGING = {
  'version': 1,
  'disable_existing_loggers': False,
  'handlers': {
    'file': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': '/django-python/django/testapp/testapp.log',
    },
  },
  'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    },
  },
}
```

and this is my code in a view file:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.info("this is an error message!!")
```

I am getting the previous logs from various modules but not the above log entry "this is an error message".

Answer (score 37):

Your logging configuration only captures logs within the `django` namespace.

This line:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

... tells the logger to use your module's name as the namespace for these logs ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#naming-loggers)). If your module is called `mymodule`, then you can catch these logs by adding something like this to your logging configuration:

```
'loggers': {
   'django' : {...},
   'mymodule': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    },
},
```

Comment: Just to add a little here, if you're placing this logging code in a view in your users module,  `__name__` will output `users.view`. So using solarissmoke's example above you would change `mymodule` to `users.view`

Comment: "modules" confused me, it is basically the app name (several apps can be part of a django project) that needs to be used, so within settings.py I had to use appname.views instead of "mymodule"

Answer (score 11):

you should add logger configuration due to your application name - something like

```
    'your_app_name': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    },
```

By now you have declared only logger for django default messages (like system errors)

---

Notice that the level of logger messages is important so when you are using

```
    logger.info("this is an error message!!")
```

method to print out message your logger's level should be INFO or more strict

Answer (score 10):

You could add the "catch all" logger to the loggers section:

```
'loggers': {
    '': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
    }
}
```

It will catch all the log messages which are not caught by Django's default loggers.

Answer (score 2):

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

after add:

```
logging.basicConfig(
    level = logging.DEBUG,
    format = '%(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
)
```

or just add settings.py :

```
import logging

    logging.basicConfig(
        level = logging.DEBUG,
        format = '%(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
    )
```

we may change format to:

```
format = '"%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s"  ',
```

or

```
format = '%(name)s %(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
```