# Django Does Not Write Logs to File

Tags: django, python-3.x, logging

I have a custom configuration for logs in `views.py` as below:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Handlers
log_handlers = {
    "terminal": logging.StreamHandler(),
    "file_debug": logging.FileHandler("/var/log/eshot-api/{name}-{level}.log".format(name=__name__, level="DEBUG"), mode="w"),
    "file_error": logging.FileHandler("/var/log/eshot-api/{name}-{level}.log".format(name=__name__, level="ERROR"), mode="w")
}

log_handlers["terminal"].setLevel(logging.INFO)
log_handlers["file_debug"].setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log_handlers["file_error"].setLevel(logging.ERROR)

# Formatters
log_formatters = {
    "terminal": logging.Formatter("[%(name)s]::[%(levelname)s]@[%(asctime)s]: %(message)s"),
    "file_debug": logging.Formatter("[%(levelname)s]@[%(asctime)s]: %(message)s"),
    "file_error": logging.Formatter("[%(asctime)s]: %(message)s")
}

for k, v in log_formatters.items():
    log_handlers[k].setFormatter(v)
```

I have created a directory as `/var/log/eshot-api` and given permission as `chmod 777` to that directory so that there will be no problem for writing.

I've also created a function as below:

```
def initial_log(request, method):
    logger.debug("{ip} requested {path} with {kwargs} in {method} method".format(ip=ipaddr(request), path=request.get_full_path(), kwargs=str(dict(request.GET)), method=method))
```

> `method` argument is a string to pass "GET" or "POST" to this function.

And I've put this at the beginning to my all `get` function of `ClassBasedView`. However, when I run and refresh a page a couple of time in order to generate some logs and look into my log files, they are empty.

And, I want to mention that this is a development server in my own computer.

---

## Environment

- django 1.9.6
- ubuntu 14.04
- python 3.5.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Django logging is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36571284/why-django-logging-is-not-working). Also show us your `LOGGING` configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your settings.py for a `LOGGING = {...}` setting and make sure that it has `disable_existing_loggers` set to `False`:

```
LOGGING = {
    ...
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    ..
}
```

Or remove the LOGGING setting completely. And add handlers to the logger:

```
logger.addHandler(log_handlers["file_debug"])
```

Also i'de like to [advise you to configure LOGGING in your settings.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/logging/#s-examples).

**Fully working example**

`urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import IndexView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view()),
]
```

`views.py`:

```
import logging
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Handlers
log_handlers = {
    "terminal": logging.StreamHandler(),
    "file_debug": logging.FileHandler("/var/log/eshot-api/{name}-{level}.log".format(name=__name__, level="DEBUG"), mode="w"),
    "file_error": logging.FileHandler("/var/log/eshot-api/{name}-{level}.log".format(name=__name__, level="ERROR"), mode="w")
}

log_handlers["terminal"].setLevel(logging.INFO)
log_handlers["file_debug"].setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log_handlers["file_error"].setLevel(logging.ERROR)

# Formatters
log_formatters = {
    "terminal": logging.Formatter("[%(name)s]::[%(levelname)s]@[%(asctime)s]: %(message)s"),
    "file_debug": logging.Formatter("[%(levelname)s]@[%(asctime)s]: %(message)s"),
    "file_error": logging.Formatter("[%(asctime)s]: %(message)s")
}

for k, v in log_formatters.items():
    log_handlers[k].setFormatter(v)

logger.addHandler(log_handlers['file_debug'])

class IndexView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        logger.debug("requested {path} with {kwargs} in method".format(path=request.get_full_path(), kwargs=str(dict(request.GET))))
        return HttpResponse('app:index')
```

`settings.py`

```
LOGGING = {
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
}
```

Comment: Thanks for documentation, I'll refer to it. However, that did not change the problem. Logs are still empty. I'll try the way of documentation and if it goes okay, then I will accept this answer as valid. Thanks...